# Pass songs from Arraylist to another activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-mediaplayer, parcelable

I want to create a very simple app that shows a list of songs and when clicking on song it opens a new Activity to show the playing statue of the song, I almost created it all but when I click on play button it doesn't play.

First activity:

```
    private Button buttonPlayStop;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    final ArrayList<Songs> songslist = new ArrayList<Songs>();
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.mimi, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.jes1s, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.matt, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.freind, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.joe, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhhh ", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.bada, R.raw.hhh));
    songslist.add(new Songs("hhhhh", "cHU CHU ", R.drawable.abby, R.raw.hhh));

    final SongsAdapter adapter = new SongsAdapter(this, songslist);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View  view, int position, long l) {
            Songs song = songslist.get(position);

            Intent anotherActivityIntent = new  Intent(FunActivity.this, playingActivity.class);
            anotherActivityIntent.putExtra("songs",songslist);
            startActivity(anotherActivityIntent);

        }
    });
```

Playing activity:

```
    public class playingActivity extends FunActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Button buttonPlayStop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playing);
    ArrayList<Songs> songs =                    getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Songs");
    buttonPlayStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

   }
```

Comment: 1. In first activity you have a line `Songs song = songslist.get(position);` to get a song but trying to send original list with `anotherActivityIntent.putExtra("songs",songslist);` 2. In playing activity you have `ArrayList<Songs> songs = ...` but seems no where to use `songs`. Which do you want to send (list of songs) or (a single song)?

Comment: ...what i want to do is whenever the user is click on any song in the list view , it shows another activity and play the chosen song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but..

First activity:

Change
`anotherActivityIntent.putExtra("songs",songslist);`

to
`anotherActivityIntent.putExtra("songs",song);`

Playing activity:

Change
`ArrayList<Songs> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Songs");`

to

```
Songs songs = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("songs");
```

And you need to add some codes in Playing activity to
 - Translate Songs to it's path (maybe better to have the path in Songs class)
 - Set the path to mMediaPlayer (Please see [MediaPlayer.setDataSource(string)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)))
 - Call mMediaPlayer.[prepare()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare())
 - Then call `mMediaPlayer.start()`

NB: Calling `mMediaPlayer.start()` in onClickListener.`onClick()` which is set to buttonPlayStop in your code seems to be a typo.

Please refer to [MediaPlayer.StateDiagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) or [MediaPlayer  developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for farther information.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
 anotherActivityIntent.putExtra("songs",songslist);
```

To

```
 anotherActivityIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("songs",songslist);
```

Also change key name you use wrong `songs` & `Songs` make same for both side

```
ArrayList<Songs> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("songs");
```

You also need to cast mMediaPlayer object before onclick lik this

```
mMediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer)findViewById(You media player id);
```

Comment: I changed it and it  still stopped  when i click on the button  : '(

Comment: and why you have extend `FunActivity` in `playingActivity` ? extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: 12-24 11:11:09.251 3651-3651/com.example.mivida.funkids E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.mivida.funkids, PID: 3651
no errors in the code but this is what happened when i click on the button it stops the app

Comment: you not cast your media player object cast it and then use

Comment: see my updted answer

Comment: I have done what you've mentioned,   
     mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 this is what i get now when i click on the button at least it doesn't stops and crash for now  but it plays nothing
12-24 11:20:43.916 4174-4174/com.example.mivida.funkids E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)

Comment: you need to set data source and  create it and all find some demo on internet regarding it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161903/discussion-between-sally-gomez-and-munir).